# WCF ServiceHost close operation timedout

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have this huge timeout problem, i have no idea how to fix it !
I am using a windows service client to connected to a WCF service via **HTTPS**

i've looked at this:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hongmeig/archive/2010/03/06/timeouts-in-wcf-and-their-default-values.aspx

Error generated on the server side

> The ServiceHost close operation timed out after 00:00:10.  This could
>   be because a client failed to close a sessionful channel within the
>   required time.  The time allotted to this operation may have been a
>   portion of a longer timeout.

Error generated on the Client side:

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException: The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.System.IDisposable.Dispose()
```

this is my binding  on the WCF Service:

```
  <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="Binding1" closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
        <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="true" />
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" />
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
```

this is code client side:

```
        wsHttpBinding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential)
       {
           CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10, 0),
           OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10, 0),
           ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0, 0),
           SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10, 0),
           TransactionFlow = false,
           MaxBufferPoolSize = 524288,
           MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647,
           ReaderQuotas =
           {
               MaxDepth = 128,
               MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue,
               MaxArrayLength = 2147483647,
               MaxBytesPerRead = 16384,
               MaxNameTableCharCount = 16384
           }
       };

        wsHttpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;

        wsHttpBinding.ReliableSession.Ordered = true;
        wsHttpBinding.ReliableSession.InactivityTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10, 0);
        wsHttpBinding.ReliableSession.Enabled = true;
        Ednpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(URL));

        myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IPoint>(wsHttpBinding, Ednpoint);
        myChannelFactory.Endpoint.Contract.SessionMode = SessionMode.Allowed;

        ClientCredentials cc = myChannelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Find<ClientCredentials>();

        cc.UserName.UserName = usr;
        cc.UserName.Password = pass;
        myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
```

I am using this code to send data like this:

```
            using (IClientChannel client = (IClientChannel)myChannelFactory.CreateChannel())
            {
                client.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
                IPoint wcfClient1 = (IPoint)client;
                for (int start = startpos; start < totalSize; start += size)
                {
                    List<Point> send = r.Skip(start).Take(size).ToList();
                    xreturn = wcfClient1.Update(send);
                    counter += 1;
                }
            }
```

Comment: I'd strongly advise against using the `using` statement with WCF proxies.  This is considered best practice (due to the way WCF implements IDisposable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the problem the application pool kept restarting on the hosted server.